# Select 3 tables with count and join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I've 3 tables tb1, users, users_credits.
My gol is to combine two select (sel1, sel2) into a single view and
display 0 in the sel2 where there isn't rows (left join?)

sel1

```
SELECT 
users.userid, 
users.datareg,
users_credits.credits,
FROM 
users,
users_credits,
WHERE
users.userid = users_credits.userid
```

Sel2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb1 where tb1.id_user = users.userid
```

table structure

```
tb1
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_user` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
`datains` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

users

```
`userid` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`datareg` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
```

users_credits

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`credits` decimal(5,0) NOT NULL,
`data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

What is the best way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  users.userid, 
        users.datareg,
        users_credits.credits,
        COALESCE(c.totalCount,0) totalCount
FROM    users
        LEFT JOIN users_credits
            ON users.userid = users_credits.userid
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id_user, COUNT(*) totalCount 
            FROM    tb1 
            GROUP   BY id_user
        ) c ON c.id_user = users.userid
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  users.userid, 
        users.datareg,
        users_credits.credits,
        COALESCE(c.totalCount,0) totalCount,
        c.max_datains
FROM    users
        LEFT JOIN users_credits
            ON users.userid = users_credits.userid
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id_user, MAX(datains) max_datains, COUNT(*) totalCount 
            FROM    tb1 
            GROUP   BY id_user
        ) c ON c.id_user = users.userid
```

**UPDATE 2**

you need to create two views for this:

1st View:

```
CREATE VIEW tbl1View
AS
SELECT  id_user, MAX(datains) max_datains, COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM    tb1 
GROUP   BY id_user
```

2nd View

```
CREATE VIEW FullView
AS
SELECT  users.userid, 
        users.datareg,
        users_credits.credits,
        COALESCE(c.totalCount,0) totalCount,
        c.max_datains
FROM    users
        LEFT JOIN users_credits
            ON users.userid = users_credits.userid
        LEFT JOIN tbl1View c ON c.id_user = users.userid
```

Comment: I receive error _MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where c.id_user = users.userid LIMIT 0, 30' at line 13_

Comment: sorry for the typo due to copy-and-paste, try it again.

Comment: Perfect! ..Only one thing: if I wanted also the last tb1.datains entered where return row? Thank you very much!

Comment: You are my hero! :D Thank a lot!!

Comment: Ops... when I try to create view with you select I receive _View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause_ :(

Comment: yes, because by design, you can't. but there is a solution for that. see my updated answer.